# Google Assistant not showing basic card when responding to action_intent_PERMISSION

Tags: json, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have two intents defined on Dialogflow. Both use a webhook fulfillment implemented in php which returns json.

One of them is activated by the action_intent_PERMISSION event. If the user granted permission, it performs an action and returns both SimpleResponse (text) and a Basic Card with some text and an image.

The problem is that the Basic Card is never shown. In the debug tab of Google Actions Simulator, I can see that the Basic Card is present in the json sent to the assistant, I see it in the Response tab in simulator, but if I look at the Debug tab in simulator, the basic card is not listed under visualElementsList.

The other intent asks user for a zip code, and then performs the same action and returns the same json as the previous intent. In this case, the Basic Card is always shown and I can see it listed under visualElementsList in the Debug tab.

I can't find why the basic card is not displayed at all when the intent is activated by the action_intent_PERMISSION event. I have been researching and looking and can't find it. Thank you for any help.

This is the response tab in simulator for the intent that shows the basic card:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[\"closestitem\"]",
  "finalResponse": {
  "richResponse": {
  "items": [
    {
      "simpleResponse": {
        "textToSpeech": "The item is xxxxx"
      }
    },
    {
      "basicCard": {
        "title": "Your Closest Item",
        "subtitle": "The item is XXXX XXXX XXXX",
        "image": {
          "url": "https://www.example.com/image.jpg",
          "accessibilityText": "Item"
        },
        "buttons": [
          {
            "title": "View More",
            "openUrlAction": {
              "url": "https://www.example.com/"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
  "responseMetadata": {
  "status": {
    "message": "Success (200)"
  },
   "queryMatchInfo": {
    "queryMatched": true,
    "intent": "XXXXXXX-2fd7-4ec3-9c88-d90cfccf8661",
    "parameterNames": [
     "zip"
   ]
 }
}
}
```

This is the content of the response tab for the intent that is not showing the basic card. I need this basic card to be shown:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[\"closestitem\",\"closestitem-followup\"]",
  "finalResponse": {
    "richResponse": {
      "items": [
        {
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "The item is XXXXXX"
          }
        },
        {
          "basicCard": {
            "title": "Your Closest Item",
            "subtitle": "The item is  XXXXXX.",
            "image": {
              "url": "https://www.example.com/image.jpg",
              "accessibilityText": "Item"
            },
            "buttons": [
              {
                "title": "View More",
                "openUrlAction": {
                  "url": "https://www.example.com/"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "XXXXXXX-3c6d-44fa-b35d-6b097c3da054"
    }
  }
}
```

The Errors tab is empty in both cases in simulator.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, except in response to a different event (action_intent_OPTION). Putting my exact same response code in a different intent that I activate directly works fine.

Comment: It's looking like it's a Simulator bug -- the card shows for me when I use the mobile app.

Comment: I've experienced this in the simulator. Try it on a device on which you are logged in and using the Assistant with the same account as you are on console.actions.google.com

Comment: Thanks it has worked on a device, looks like this is a simulator bug.